# Returning Value from Actor

Tags: scala, actor

For the following Actor that checks divisibility by 3:

```
class CheckActor(actor: Actor) extends Actor {  
 println("created actor")

 var sum = 0
 def act = loop {
    react {
        case x:Int if (x % 3 == 0) => sum+=1
            ...
        case "calcSum" => sum
        case _ => 
    }
 }
}
```

When I try to get the value of `sum` from the CheckActor instance...

> `actor1 ! "calcSum" // actor1 is of type "CheckActor"`

I see this error on the type mismatch of sum1.

```
$>scalac Count.scala
Count.scala:38: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: Int
                val sum1: Int = actor1 ! "calcSum"
                                       ^
one error found
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The action of sending a message (`actor ! foo`) returns `Unit` because there is nothing to return, you fire and forget (asynchronous). If you want/expect some sort of response back, use `ask` or `?` instead - this will return to you a `Future[Any]` that you can use.

On a related note, it looks like you're using Scala Actors, I suggest you look at Akka (http://akka.io/) if you want to look into actors - as of Scala 2.10.0 Scala Actors are deprecated and replaced by Akka.